Angular Module federation - how to import and use a shared module from another mf-project
I am using module federation for microfrontends, and in each microfrontend I use atomic architecture. I have a module called atoms that contains and exports many components. I want to use these components from the other microfront. How I do this?
I looked for information on the subject but the only thing I found is importing and using modules in the routing file.

To me this sounds like more of a use case for a library (ie create a lib and reference it on package.json of each MF) than a micro-frontend .
But tbf Im not familiar with this atomic architecture , not sure what it means

otherwise, if they are all on the same project, you will need to leverage typescript paths for that , will be on tsconfig.json prop "paths": { "atoms": [ "path1", "path2" ] }
